# How to solve report generation issue on Azure?

Tags: azure, visual-studio, c#-3.0, rdlc

I am facing some issue when I published over azure it's  not working please tell me if any person have a solution about it.

```
public ActionResult GenerateReport(string ReportName)     
        {
            LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();
            localReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Areas/RemoteAnalysis/rptAlarm.rdlc");
            List<clsReport> lstOverallData = new List<clsReport>();

            using (DBClass context = new DBClass())
            {
                context.AddParameter("@FileID", Convert.ToInt32(Session["FileID"]));
                context.AddParameter("@UserID", Session["UserName"]);
                DataTable dtReportData = context.getData("GetRouteDetailForReport", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                if (dtReportData.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dtReportData.Rows)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            lstOverallData.Add(new clsReport
                            {
                                FileID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Fileid"]),
                                PlantID = Convert.ToString(dr["PlantID"]),
                                PlantName = Convert.ToString(dr["PlantName"]),
                                AreaID = Convert.ToString(dr["AreaID"]),
                                AreaName = Convert.ToString(dr["AreaName"]),
                                TrainID = Convert.ToString(dr["TrainID"]),
                                TrainName = Convert.ToString(dr["TrainName"]),
                                MachineID = Convert.ToString(dr["MachineID"]),
                                MachineName = Convert.ToString(dr["MachineName"]),
                                PointID = Convert.ToString(dr["PointID"]),
                                PointName = Convert.ToString(dr["PointName"]),
                                AalrmID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PointAlarmID"]),
                                AlarmName = Convert.ToString(dr["AlarmName"]),
                                HighValue = Convert.ToDouble(dr["HighValue"]),
                                LowValue = Convert.ToDouble(dr["LowValue"]),
                                MeasurementTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-04-17 14:44:02.293"),
                                OverallChnlA = Convert.ToDouble(dr["OverallValueChnlA"]),
                                UnitChnlA = Convert.ToString(dr["OverallUnitChnlA"]),
                                OverallChnlB = Convert.ToDouble(dr["OverallValueChnlB"]),
                                UnitChnlB = Convert.ToString(dr["OverallUnitChnlB"]),
                                DataID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DataID"])
                            });
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw ex;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            //code changes from here on 5 march 2021..
            ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("dsOverall", lstOverallData);
            localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
            localReport.Refresh();
            string reportType = "";   //"PDF";     //Enter downloading format according to your choice/if condition
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string fileNameExtension;          
            string format = "";
            string filename = "";
            string deviceInfo = "";
            //The DeviceInfo settings should be changed based on the reportType            
            if (ReportName == "pdf")
            {
               reportType = "PDF";
               format = "application/pdf";
               filename = "AlaramReport.pdf";

               deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" +
          "  <OutputFormat>pdf</OutputFormat>" +
          "  <PageTitle> Report</PageTitle>" +
          "  <PageWidth>9.5in</PageWidth>" +
          "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
          "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
          "  <MarginLeft>0.5in</MarginLeft>" +
          "  <MarginRight>0.5in</MarginRight>" +
          "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
          "</DeviceInfo>";
            }
            else if (ReportName == "doc")
            {
                reportType = "Word";
                format = "application/doc";
                filename = "AlaramReport.doc";

                deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" +
           "  <OutputFormat>doc</OutputFormat>" +
           "  <PageTitle> Report</PageTitle>" +
           "  <PageWidth>9.5in</PageWidth>" +
           "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
           "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
           "  <MarginLeft>0.5in</MarginLeft>" +
           "  <MarginRight>0.5in</MarginRight>" +
           "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
           "</DeviceInfo>";
            }
            else if (ReportName == "xls")
            {
                reportType = "Excel";
                format = "application/xls";
                filename = "AlaramReport.xls";

                deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" +
           "  <OutputFormat>xls</OutputFormat>" +
           "  <PageTitle> Report</PageTitle>" +
           "  <PageWidth>9.5in</PageWidth>" +
           "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
           "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
           "  <MarginLeft>0.5in</MarginLeft>" +
           "  <MarginRight>0.5in</MarginRight>" +
           "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
           "</DeviceInfo>";
            }
            else if (ReportName == "jpg")
            {
                reportType = "Image";
                format = "application/jpg";
                filename = "AlaramReport.jpg";

                deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" +
           "  <OutputFormat>jpg</OutputFormat>" +
           "  <PageTitle> Report</PageTitle>" +
           "  <PageWidth>9.5in</PageWidth>" +
           "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
           "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
           "  <MarginLeft>0.5in</MarginLeft>" +
           "  <MarginRight>0.5in</MarginRight>" +
           "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
           "</DeviceInfo>";
            }
            else 
            {
                reportType = "PDF";
                format = "application/pdf";
                filename = "AlaramReport.pdf";

                deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" +
           "  <OutputFormat>pdf</OutputFormat>" +
           "  <PageTitle> Report</PageTitle>" +
           "  <PageWidth>9.5in</PageWidth>" +
           "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
           "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
           "  <MarginLeft>0.5in</MarginLeft>" +
           "  <MarginRight>0.5in</MarginRight>" +
           "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
           "</DeviceInfo>";
            }

            //Render the report 
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streams;
            byte[] renderedBytes;
            renderedBytes = localReport.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
            ViewBag.Title = "Alarm Report";
            return File(renderedBytes, format, filename);

        }
```

The above one is my code which is used to generate a report on local serer but when I publish on Azure then it was not working and shows me an error like server error. How to resolve this issue please anyone tell me. tried lots of code for this issue but nothing to work.

Comment: Can you [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68918387/edit) and post the exact error messages?

Comment: Actually in the above code word and excel part is working and download the document easily but when i try to download the my file in pdf it's shows internal server error.

Comment: Your code seems fine to me, as you can run it locally as well. You can debug by adding Try/Catch block at `localReport.Render` and `return File(renderedBytes, format, filename);`, etc. In those `Catch` block, use `response.write(exception.Message)` or `stacktrace` (or use whatever means you can to save the error message). This can show what exactly is the error instead of generic internal server error.